# PostgreSQL DB access - Authentication type 10 error

Tags: android, postgresql, authentication

In order to control PostgreSQL DB outside,
I downloaded serveral PostgreSQL clients on my cell phone.
(Galaxy S10+, Android ver 11)

But all of clients app showed me same message as below:
"The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver"

I googled many of relevant pages, and I found some advice about MD5, SHA,
so I tried to change MD5-SHA in pg_hba.conf, and also postgressql.conf,
but it was not helpful for me.

current `pg_hba.conf`:

```
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               scram-sha-256
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```

`postgresql.conf` contains:

```
password_encryption = md5       # md5 or scram-sha-256
```

So please let me know how to solve this problem.

Comment: The last line in your `pg_hba.conf` is never used, as PostgreSQL uses the first line that matches the incoming connection. Upgrade your client software.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Thank you for your answer, but.. it doesn't matter whether remove last line or not to access PostgreSQL :)

Comment: That's what I was trying to say. Did you update your PostgreSQL client?